# Can I set how long ssh-agent keeps keys in memory? 

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'd like to have my keyfiles leave memory after a certain amount of disuse. Is there a way to make `ssh-agent` expire keys faster? It feels like it keeps them in memory and not needing a passphrase for really long periods of time.

Comment: Have you seen the `-t` switch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pass the `-t` option to [`ssh-agent`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-agent&sektion=1) or to [`ssh-add`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh-add&sektion=1). The argument can be a number of seconds or [use other time units](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd_config&sektion=5#TIME_FORMATS).

Comment: Since Ubuntu often launches the GUI passphrase tool automatically, is there a way that I can specify how long to have the key live for in a configuration file somewhere?

Comment: @TKKocheran `ssh-agent` is invoked from `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent`, so it's difficult to change it as a per-account setting. It may be possible, depending on the version of Ubuntu and the display manager and the desktop environment. Or you may be able to tune the GUI passphrase tool to pass `-t`, I don't know anything about it.

Comment: @TKKocheran @Gilles The "graphical" agent from Gnome (Debian Squeeze) is used over `ssh-agent` by default, and to my knowledge, there is no way to configure it so it will not keep the keys forever. There is two workarounds: disable the Gnome agent and use `ssh-agent`, or launch a command with `screen` like: `while sleep 1h ; do ssh-add -D ; done`